# VB.NET Dispose Bitmap in RAM wont work

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, overflow, dispose, ram

first of all i am relative new to Visual Basic.NET and i stuck on an problem here.
I started to code a screen2gif recorder. In main purpose it works. But if i record more than 15 to 20 seconds my ram overloads and exceed the 3,5 Gb limit for x32bit applications. The problem is that the bitmaps i create stack over and over.

```
Private Function getBitmap(ByVal pCtrl As Control) As Bitmap
    Dim myBmp As Bitmap
    If myBmp IsNot Nothing Then
        myBmp.Dispose()
    End If
    myBmp = New Bitmap(pCtrl.Width, pCtrl.Height)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBmp)

    Dim p As New Point(pCtrl.Parent.Width - pCtrl.Parent.ClientRectangle.Width - 4, pCtrl.Parent.Height - pCtrl.Parent.ClientRectangle.Height - 4)
    g.CopyFromScreen(pCtrl.Parent.Location + pCtrl.Location + p, Point.Empty, myBmp.Size)
    Dim LocalMousePosition As Point
    LocalMousePosition = panelTranspacrency.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
    Cursor.Draw(g, New Rectangle(New Point(LocalMousePosition.X, LocalMousePosition.Y), Cursor.Size))
    Return myBmp
    myBmp.Dispose()
    g.Dispose()

End Function

Private Sub tmrWork_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrWork.Tick
    counter += 1
    Dim bm As Bitmap
    bm = getBitmap(Me.panelTranspacrency)
    bm.Save(My.Settings.outputpath & "\temp\" & counter & ".png", Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    bm.Dispose()
End Sub
```

So this is my code to create the bitmaps and save them to disk.
I mention that i used the .Dispose command but the ram wont free.

Please take a look and give me a hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that top method is returning a bitmap, it is the responsibility of the code calling it to dispose of it.  The code after the `Return myBmp` to dispose of stuff is never ever going to run (how can it?)  The code at the top `If myBmp IsNot Nothing Then` wont do much because you just declared myBmp the line before

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Plutonix . I'm already aware of this point. But i think i am doing this right because as you can see i dispose the bmp in the called function. Or am i completly wrong ?

Comment: The function exits after `Return myBmp`. Any code after that will never get executed. Also, your first `If`-statement is useless: `If myBmp IsNot Nothing Then myBmp.Dispose()` - you have just created the `myBmp` variable so it will **always** be `Nothing` when that statement runs.

Comment: Right now it is your graphics object leaking. You've got to call `g.Dispose()` before the function exits at `Return myBmp`.

Comment: *the bitmaps i create stack over and over* what does that even mean?  If the timer is on a really short interval you can seem to run out of resources because GC cant keep up with the code.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] - also check the tag text for `overflow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBmp)
```

to

```
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBmp)
```

and put `End Using` after your `Return myBmp`. And you should do the same with

```
Using bm As Bitmap = getBitmap(Me.panelTranspacrency)
```

And remove all your explicit .Dispose calls as well.

**Docs**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement